# SQL Server: check whether a Trigger is Enabled or Disabled?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers

How we can see which Trigger is Enabled or Disabled in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Using [`sys.triggers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188746.aspx)

```
SELECT name, is_disabled FROM sys.triggers
```

Comment: Thanks! it is working. so if is_disabled = 0 means Trigger is enabled and is_disabled = 1 means Disable am i right ?

Comment: If you need to perform an action when a specific trigger is disable,  you can use:           if exists (SELECT name, is_disabled FROM sys.triggers where name ='MyTriggerName' and is_disabled=1) /* perform the action */

Answer (score 8):

In big databases you usually don't know the table for the trigger.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(parent_id) [table_name],[name] [trigger_name],is_disabled
FROM sys.triggers
```

Answer (score 5):

Descriptive State of Trigger help you to clearly ready about status. Also excluding triggers not related with user tables.

Check the below code:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(parent_id) [Table_Name],[name] [Trigger_Name],
Case When is_disabled=0 then 'Enabled' Else 'Disabled' End [Trigger_Status], is_disabled
FROM sys.triggers 
where OBJECT_NAME(parent_id) is not null
```