# How to get the list of active triggers on a database?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

My application is based on a sql server db.

All customers has the same db except for customizations.

Some customizations include: new tables, modified tables, custom views, custom triggers...

When I run the software update some scripts are executed. Now I manually disable triggers and reenable after the scripts are done.

Anyway I would like automatically to disable all the triggers (that are enabled, may be some of them could be already disabled) and then reenable them at the end.

Not to reinvent the whell, how to do that?

**How to get only the active triggers on the current db?**

Once I got this I can programmatically create and run the

```
DISABLE TRIGGER triggername ON TABLENAME

ENABLE TRIGGER triggername ON TABLENAME
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server: check whether a Trigger is Enabled or Disabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136937/sql-server-check-whether-a-trigger-is-enabled-or-disabled)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
select objectproperty(object_id('TriggerName'), 'ExecIsTriggerDisabled')
```

1 means true, 0 means false obviously

Use Jeff O's query and modify it a bit

```
SELECT  
       TAB.name as Table_Name 
     , TRIG.name as Trigger_Name
     , TRIG.is_disabled  --or objectproperty(object_id('TriggerName'), 'ExecIsTriggerDisabled')
FROM [sys].[triggers] as TRIG 
inner join sys.tables as TAB 
on TRIG.parent_id = TAB.object_id
```

or add it as a where clause.

```
where TRIG.is_disabled = 0 -- or 1 depends on what you want
```

Comment: I choose this as answer even if all were correct, this just simply is "perfect".

Comment: Note : "Database Triggers" do not have an associated table, thus its "parent_id" is 0.  Thus the "inner join" above will not match.  Just for future readers as this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 13):

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.triggers
WHERE is_disabled = 0
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT 
       TAB.name as Table_Name
     , TRIG.name as Trigger_Name  
FROM [sys].[triggers] as TRIG
inner join sys.tables as TAB
on TRIG.parent_id = TAB.object_id
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    TAB.name as Table_Name,
    TRIG.name as Trigger_Name,
    Comments.Text TriggerText
FROM [sys].[triggers] as TRIG
    Inner Join sys.tables as TAB on TRIG.parent_id = TAB.object_id
    Inner Join syscomments Comments On TRIG.object_id = Comments.id
WHERE
    TRIG.is_disabled = 0;
```

is complete solution

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from sys.triggers
```

Here object_id is for table so from joining `sys.table` you can get table name

Answer (score 1):

You can query the [sys.triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188746.aspx) view.

Answer (score 1):

```
select so.name, text
from sysobjects so, syscomments sc
where type = 'TR'
and so.id = sc.id
and text like '%related_table_name%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query that occurs when you do a refresh on "Database Triggers" in SSMS.

```
SELECT
tr.name AS [Name],
'Server[@Name=' + quotename(CAST(
        serverproperty(N'Servername')
       AS sysname),'''') + ']' + '/Database[@Name=' + quotename(db_name(),'''') + ']' + '/DdlTrigger[@Name=' + quotename(tr.name,'''') + ']' AS [Urn],
tr.is_disabled AS [IsEnabled]
FROM
sys.triggers AS tr
WHERE
(tr.parent_class = 0)
ORDER BY
[Name] ASC
```

Using that, I've created a version (that enhances the accepted answer) to include the database triggers.

Note the left join and the COALESCE check.

```
SELECT  
       COALESCE(TAB.name, 'DATABASE') as TargetObjectName
     , TRIG.name as Trigger_Name
     , TRIG.is_disabled  --or objectproperty(object_id('TriggerName'), 'ExecIsTriggerDisabled')
     -- select *
FROM [sys].[triggers] as TRIG 
left join sys.tables as TAB 
on TRIG.parent_id = TAB.object_id 
WHERE
/* (TRIG.parent_class = 0) and */
TRIG.is_disabled = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

//Use Your Database

```
use [your_database_Name]

Select * from sys.triggers where is_disabled=0
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer?