# How to check that MSSQL trigger is runnable?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

How can I check that target trigger is runnable?
In Oracle I can simple select it from user_object table:

```
SELECT status FROM user_objects WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TRIGGER' and object_name='trigger_name'
```

Can I do something similar in MSSQL?

---

**Solution**: [Find broken objects in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330521/find-broken-objects-in-sql-server)

Comment: You can check if the trigger is [enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136937/sql-server-check-whether-a-trigger-is-enabled-or-disabled)? [And here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330521/find-broken-objects-in-sql-server) if you need to find broken artifacts.

Comment: No. When I have Oracle trigger with some error (like insert into non-existing table) then trigger is enabled but is invalid. So I am looking for way how to validate my mssql triggers.
And thanks I think that broken artifacts is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent validation in SQL Server regarding the Oracle behavior described in the comments on the question. If the Trigger exists and is enabled, it is runnable. It might error, but SQL Server will at least attempt execution.