# MSSQL After Insert Trigger not executing after database restore

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I restored a SQL 2k5 Database to a SQL 2014 server (*Note this is a SQL Web Edition instance*) and it does not seem to execute at all.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tInsertTransactionsSnapshot]
ON  [GDL_TNA].[dbo].[TRANSACTIONS] 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @FirstRecord int
DECLARE @LastRecord int
DECLARE @MSTSQ int
DECLARE @EventDate varchar(50)
SET @FirstRecord = (SELECT TOP 1 T_ID FROM INSERTED ORDER BY T_ID ASC)
SET @LastRecord = (SELECT TOP 1 T_ID FROM INSERTED ORDER BY T_ID DESC)

insert into GDL_TNA.dbo.dbg(Dbgfirst,dbgLast) VALUES (@FirstRecord,@LastRecord)

WHILE @FirstRecord <= @LastRecord
BEGIN
    SET @MSTSQ = (SELECT MST_SQ FROM INSERTED WHERE T_ID = @FirstRecord)
    SET @EventDate = (SELECT T_Date FROM INSERTED WHERE T_ID = @FirstRecord)

    IF EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM GDL_TNA.dbo.SNAPSHOTs WHERE MST_SQ = @MSTSQ AND SS_EVENT_DATE = @EventDate AND SS_ACTIVE = 1 AND SS_TYPE = 'TRANSACTION')
    BEGIN
        UPDATE GDL_TNA.dbo.SNAPSHOTs SET SS_ACTIVE = 0 WHERE MST_SQ = @MSTSQ AND SS_EVENT_DATE = @EventDate AND SS_ACTIVE = 1 AND SS_TYPE = 'TRANSACTION'
    END

    INSERT INTO GDL_TNA.dbo.SNAPSHOTs
    (
         [SS_TYPE]
        ,[SS_EVENT]
        ,[MST_SQ]
        ,[MD_ACTIVE]
        ,[MST_FIRST_NAME]
        ,[MST_LAST_NAME]
        ,[MD_SHIFTSTART]
        ,[MD_SHIFTEND]
        ,[COMP_ID]
        ,[DEPT_ID]
        ,[FUNC_ID]
        ,[MST_PREVIOUS_FIRST_NAME]
        ,[MST_PREVIOUS_LAST_NAME]
        ,[MST_RATE_NORMAL]
        ,[MST_RATE_TIMEANDHALF]
        ,[MST_RATE_DOUBLE]
        ,[MST_RATE_SPECIAL]
        ,[SS_EVENT_ID]
        ,[SS_EVENT_DATE]
        ,[SS_EVENT_START]
        ,[SS_EVENT_END]
        ,[SS_EVENT_APPROVED]
        ,[SS_EVENT_RATETYPE]
    )
    SELECT
         'TRANSACTION'
        ,'INSERT'
        ,MST_SQ
        ,MD_ACTIVE
        ,MST_FIRST_NAME
        ,MST_LAST_NAME
        ,MD_SHIFTSTART
        ,MD_SHIFTEND
        ,COMP_ID
        ,DEPT_ID
        ,FUNC_ID
        ,MST_PREVIOUS_FIRST_NAME
        ,MST_PREVIOUS_LAST_NAME
        ,MST_RATE_NORMAL
        ,MST_RATE_TIMEANDHALF
        ,MST_RATE_DOUBLE
        ,MST_RATE_SPECIAL
        ,(
            SELECT T_ID
            FROM INSERTED
            WHERE T_ID = @FirstRecord
         )
        ,(
            SELECT T_Date
            FROM INSERTED
            WHERE T_ID = @FirstRecord
         )
        ,ISNULL((
            SELECT  
                CASE
                    WHEN len(T_TIMEIN) = 6 THEN left(T_TIMEIN,2) + ':' + right(left(T_TIMEIN,4),2) + ':' + right(T_TIMEIN,2) + '.000'
                    WHEN len(T_TIMEIN) < 6 THEN '0'+left(T_TIMEIN,1) + ':' + right(left(T_TIMEIN,3),2) + ':' + right(T_TIMEIN,2) + '.000'
                END
            FROM INSERTED
            WHERE T_ID = @FirstRecord
         ),'00:00:00.000')           
        ,ISNULL((
            SELECT 
                CASE
                    WHEN len(T_TIMEOUT) = 6 THEN left(T_TIMEOUT,2) + ':' + right(left(T_TIMEOUT,4),2) + ':' + right(T_TIMEOUT,2) + '.000'
                    WHEN len(T_TIMEOUT) < 6 THEN '0'+left(T_TIMEOUT,1) + ':' + right(left(T_TIMEOUT,3),2) + ':' + right(T_TIMEOUT,2) + '.000'
                END
            FROM INSERTED
            WHERE T_ID = @FirstRecord
         ),'00:00:00.000')
        ,1
        ,1
    FROM GDL_TNA.dbo.MASTER_DETAILS
    WHERE MST_SQ = @MSTSQ

    SET @FirstRecord = @FirstRecord + 1
END
END
```

### Steps I have Taken

1. [Check Trigger Status](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8136951/1611516): ***SELECT name, is_disabled FROM sys.triggers*** (All Enabled)
2. Drop & Recreate Triggers on 2014 instance
3. Ran a Recompile of table with ***sp_recompile***

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add some print statements to see whether those while clauses and Exists clauses are passing  ?